# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied..... Error

Tags: c#

I want to open one document file on our website. For that I write following code.

```
try
{
      Process proc = new Process();
      proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Quatation/PREMIUMQUOTATION1.doc"));
      proc.Start();
}
catch (WebException we)
{

}
```

It runs locally very fine but web on web server it gives me an error like

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied?

Please suggest, what should I do?

Comment: make sure you have enough permission to access that particular document

Comment: you need to assign permission to the document.

Comment: take a look here, its the possible answer: [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied Error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194146/system-componentmodel-win32exception-access-is-denied-error

Comment: what should i have to do for permission access

Comment: @ rahul :- how to do assign permission to the document

Comment: check the application pool's Identity property

Comment: Wait . . . you're trying to open the document on  your website, as in, open an instance of Word on the server console?  I don't think that will work . . .

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when my .NET Target Framework was set to 4.5.2. I fixed it by changing the target framework version to 4.5. To do this using Visual Studio 2015, open Solution Explorer, right click on your solution and click Properties. The "Target Framework" should be set to ".NET Framework 4.5". Additionally, if you previously built with a target framework other than 4.5, you may have a `<compiler>` section in your web.config, and this may throw an error when you build. Just remove this section to fix the issue. Removing it should not cause any problems.

I wrote a short article about this [here](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/07/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception.html) that has a couple other things to try that didn't work for me but might work for you.

Also check out [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184429/problems-publishing-a-website-on-smarterasp-net-with-csc-exe-file-included/35207055#35207055) which also helped numerous people with this error!

Answer (score 2):

may be your SQL server is off
check it in services and start it

Answer (score 2):

My problem solve with this

In IIS Manage->Pool Application->Advance Setting->Identity 
change to Custom Account and set Administrator User

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't changed the service logon user. You can do it from service control manager by right clicking the service and go to the Logon tab. 
Then add user as Service Logon User

Or you can do it from the command line:

```
sc config ServiceName obj= Domain\user password= pass
```

Note the space between `obj=` and `Domain\user` it is not a typo. It is required. The same for `password=`.

Answer (score 0):

Goto windows explorer and right click on the folder "~/Quatation/". Select properties and pick the Security tab to give permissions. In the case where your application pool under which the web application runs is using a domain account, you will need to give that specific domain account permission.

Comment: It is because you are running locally under your account which probably has Admin access, thus not complaining about access permissions. When deployed on the server it will be running under the IIS user which wont have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while running my website from local IIS, after spending some time reading the project properties, found that, certain changes to the project properties were not saved...

Once it was saved, the error went away...

I got this error while I was working in visual studio 2017, using dotNet framework 4.5, in MVC project...

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this exception maybe you don't have the administration rights to your system so check with your admin and ask for the rights. If you do have administrator rights please open your IDE(e.g Visual Studio as an Administrator).You might also get this exception if you are trying to access the processes of 32 bit configuration system but your system has 64 bit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using .Net 4.5.2 and IIS 8.5.9
>
> In IIS Manage->Pool Application->Advance Setting->Identity change
> ApplicationPoolIdentity to Custom Account and set Administrator User