# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied on ixwebhosting

Tags: file, exe, web-hosting

I will host my site on ixwebhosting.
I tested my site several time. 
On my local server, 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied' error doesn't occur. but On ixwebhosting, it occurs. 
I don't know why does this error occur.
Definitely File is in exactly path.

Do I have to set options??
It's first time manage site on ixwebhosting.

Thank you.

Comment: Following URL would be helpful to you...... http://forums.asp.net/t/1982501.aspx?System+ComponentModel+Win32Exception+The+system+cannot+find+the+file+specified ........If not, contact your web hosting provider and make sure you have correct permission on your wwwroot folder.

Comment: Thank you for advice, I contacted. but they can't give permission to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application runs under admin account locally, when you deploy it to web server, it will be running under the IIS user. Hence, assigning necessary permissions to IIS user is essential to make your application running on web server. Also, make sure that Application pool identity of your application is Network service. Following threads will be helpful to you.

[System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied..... Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419181/system-componentmodel-win32exception-access-is-denied-error)

[System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194146/system-componentmodel-win32exception-access-is-denied-error)

Answer (score 8):

Simply remove/comment the codedom section from the Web.config, this solves the problem.

Comment: This helped me! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Peter,
I had a very similar problem and nothing was working for me. I fixed it by changing the .NET framework version to 4.5 instead of 4.5.2.

I wrote a [short article](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/07/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception.html) about it which shows you how to change the framework version and includes other solutions to try that might fix the error for your. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your good information. but ixweb customer serivce said that  I can't use exe file because of security.

Answer (score 0):

Just to increase answer base, I solved this by running my webApi from Visual Studio. Basically, this error comes when there's a malfunctioning api connection.