# Getting error after deploy Google calendar app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-calendar-api

I'm facing "access denied" message after deploy my App to server. While running it on my PC it worked perfectly.

This is part of my code where I get the authorization (as I said above it worked on my PC).

```
Private Function GetCalendarService() As CalendarService

    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Using stream = New FileStream(Server.MapPath("~\credentials.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim credPath As String = Server.MapPath("~\token.json")
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
    End Using
    Return New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential})

End Function
```

But for some reason after the deploy I am receiving the error "Access denied"...

I have authorized my URI in the Google console.

The error message is :

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the tag of the programming language that you use? Also what is the exact error message? It will be also helpful if you have a screenshot of it so the community can further help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied on ixwebhosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457655/system-componentmodel-win32exception-0x80004005-access-is-denied-on-ixwebhost)

Comment: Thank you by the hint Serenity, but no one of those suggestion solved my issue.