# Azure SQL server database [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-deployment

I have managed to deploy a web application on Azure with VS2015 and I have created a database but something seems to be wrong configured in the web.config because I get an error. 
I have followed a tutorial that helped me through the process.

Here is the link, maybe someone finds it useful: [Link to pluralsight tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=dfd3d2ac-31d3-4b97-86b9-891e7b0b3578&mode=live&clip=5&course=developing-dotnet-microsoft-azure-getting-started)

Well, when I have finished, I got this:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj0nd.png)

My connection string:

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={database};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={xxx};Password={xxxx};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have tried several solutions on stackoverflow like changing the target framework version to 4.5. from 4.5.2. [Link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419181/system-componentmodel-win32exception-access-is-denied-error) Did not work for me. I would be so greatful if someone could help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET 5 then configure your connection string in appsettings.json file.