# How to execute .cmd file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, command, console-application

I have a command(.cmd) file with few steps in it. 
I want to execute this file using a C# code

This is the code I wrote-

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\zrana\Desktop\"
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\zrana\Desktop\test.cmd"
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

When I run this program, I get an exception **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'**. 
Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Please read this [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194146/system-componentmodel-win32exception-access-is-denied-error) and this [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied](https://support.microsoft.com/de-at/help/867466/access-is-denied-error-message-when-you-run-a-batch-job-on-a-windows-s)

Comment: I checked the folder and the cmd.exe properties. The permissions look okay. I also tried running the code above in administrator mode. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because your executable doesn't run in **Adminstrator** mode.
Try to build your project and then from the build output folder right click on the `exe` and choose "Run as Administrator" if that doesn't help let me know, please.

---

**Update**

Please try running your `cmd` file by calling it from the Windows `cmd.exe` like this:

```cs
var testCmd = @"/C C:\Users\zrana\Desktop\test.cmd";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", testCmd);
```

Comment: I still get the same error. It is in a winforms application that I am trying to run the .cmd file

Comment: @ZankhanaRana could you please confirm that the path for the `cmd` file you are running is correct?

Comment: @ZankhanaRana also please try adding manifest file (ex: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629067/How-to-add-a-manifest-file-in-my-project) like this: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` or edit your existing manifest.

Comment: I checked and confirmed that the path is correct. And I added a manifest file with the line in the previous comment. I still get the same error.

Comment: @ZankhanaRana I've updated the post. Would you please try the updated version?

Comment: Okay, the solution above worked. could you please explain what is wrong with what I have done and this works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212278/discussion-between-arsen-khachaturyan-and-zankhana-rana).